# Formatting form's field with Boostrap and Django

Tags: django, forms

I have a form which is generated by a model in Django made by text area, choice field, toggle field and so on like:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    workerID = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    dashboardURL = models.URLField(blank=True)
    centralinaVecchia = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And I've styled the form with

```
class StartWorker(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ('testTitle', 'testDescription', 'centralinaVecchia')
        labels = {
            "testTitle": _("Titolo"),
            "testDescription": _("Descrizione"),
            "centralinaVecchia": _("Centralina Vecchia?"),
        }

        widgets = {
            'testTitle': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'testDescription': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'centralinaVecchia': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class':'form-check-input'}),
```

The issue is that, if every single field is correctly formated one below the other, the check box is located in a weired way (see screenshot)

[image]

I'm unabel to style it like the rest of the form. According to the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/forms/checks-radios/) I need to add the checkbox inside a `<div class="form-check"></div>` but I do not know how to do it in Django

The template is as simple as

```
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %} {{ form }}
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
      Submit
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you thought of trying [crispy forms](https://pypi.org/project/django-crispy-forms/)? It allows you to give it bootstrap formatting with just one tag. Like this: `{{ form|crispy }}`.

Comment: @Martin never heard of it. I'll have a look. Seems the version for Boostrap v5 is still in beta tho

Comment: You can use django_crispy which is a wondeful library that allows you to setup a layout of the form using python code or you can setup your template using bootstrap and instead of adding the all form like this {{ form }} you could add every single field separately like this <div class="row">{{ form.centralinaVecchia }}</div> I normally choose the second option.

Comment: @Marco yeah, I guess I'll go with the manual mode

Comment: @NicoCaldo actually I use both crispy and detail template like here: <div class="row mb-3 align-items-end">
                            <div class="col-10">
                                {{  form.bus | as_crispy_field }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-2">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn-primary" style="font-size: 2rem;"
                                       value="OK">
                            </div>
                        </div>

Comment: You could also pass a customized template to the [`CheckboxInput`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.CheckboxInput) via the parameter `template_name`. That gives you the functionality to "just" achieve what you want for that specific widget.

Comment: @Tarquinius that could be the right choice for me atm, I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

#### forms.py

```py
class StartWorker(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = "__all__"
        labels = {
            "workerID":"Worker",
            "dashboardURL":"Dashboard Url",
            "centralinaVecchia":"Centralina Vecchia?",
        }

        widgets = {
            'workerID': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'dashboardURL': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'centralinaVecchia': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class':'form-check-input'}),}
```

#### Html Code

```html
<div class="container p-5">
  <div class="row mx-auto">
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label  class="form-label">{{form.workerID.label_tag}}</label>
      {{form.workerID}}
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label  class="form-label">{{form.dashboardURL.label_tag}}</label>
      {{form.dashboardURL}}
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3 form-check">
      <label  class="form-label">{{form.centralinaVecchia.label_tag}}</label>
      {{form.centralinaVecchia}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Output in Browser

[image]